# For each of the following sets A, B prove or disprove whether A ⊆ B and B ⊆ A

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Would this proof be sufficient for just proving B ⊆ A alone?

$A = \{x ∈ \Bbb Z : ∃y∈\Bbb Z,x = 5y + 1\},\ $$B = \{x ∈ \Bbb Z : ∃y∈\Bbb Z, x = 10y − 9\}$

Suppose some arbitrary element x is in B. if x∈B, then x∈A by definition of B ⊆ A.
Also, by the definition of set B,

x = 10y - 9 for some y
= 10y - 9 + 10 -10
= 10y - 10 + 1
= 5(2y-5) + 1

Since, 2y-5 is an integer, x is in A by definition.
Therefore B ⊆ A.

Comment: It will be $2y-2$ instead of $2y-5$. Otherwise it is okay.

Comment: For brevity: Replace your first two lines by: 'Take $x \in B$. Then'. Skip the second line of the 4 equations. Otherwise, fine!